# Puppet change mysql datadir only if it is installed first time

Tags: mysql, puppet, installation

I want to use puppet to install Percona server with YUM repository. The default datadir directory should be /mysql. This is required to be consistent with existing directory structure.

Comment: Yes, changing the data directory is a bad idea.

Comment: what is the best practice here? The servers have new mount @ /mysql

Comment: this may work? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23110/how-to-install-packages-to-a-custom-location-in-centos6

Comment: Why are you creating a new mount at `/mysql` That is not a standard location, anyone using the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) would look for something.  I would expect data like that to be under `/var`, or possibly `/srv/`.

Comment: It is a long story from the company. But currently all mysql instances were installed that way. My first step is to automate it by puppet.

Comment: yum --relocate did not work, here is the error. "Command line error: no such option: --relocate"

Comment: I suggest to use symlink in situations like this. You can use it for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install mysql in an alternative directory, using puppetlabs mysql module in this way, if you want to install percona first you need to add the percona repository for your distro.

file mysql.pp

```
  class { '::mysql::server':
         service_name => 'mysql',
         package_name => 'Percona-Server-server-56',
         root_password    => 'mysqlpassword01',
         override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'datadir' => '/mysql' } }
    }
```

Now I test if the class works well with this options

```
puppet apply mysql.pp --environment testing

ps aux | grep datadir
root      4591  0.0  0.1 108168  1572 ?        S    03:29   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql     4759  0.1  3.1 392104 32216 ?        Sl   03:29   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

`ls -l /mysql` output

```
[root@puppetserver ~]# ls -l /mysql/
total 20488
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 10485760 17 giu 03:29 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  5242880 17 giu 03:29 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  5242880 17 giu 03:29 ib_logfile1
drwx------. 2 mysql root      4096 17 giu 03:29 mysql
drwx------. 2 mysql root      4096 17 giu 03:29 test
```

anyway, if the directory /mysql exist the mysql install script doesn't delete anything.

Comment: does this module support Percona 5.6? That is the version I am installing.

Comment: i don't use Percona, but you can try to configure Percona Repo and using the module class "class mysql::server" with package_name => 'percona-package-name'

Comment: @Max I will update my answer and it could be useful if you update your question too.